# How to extract two separate groups in regex?

Tags: regex, awk, sed

In this text, I'm trying to extract all of the titles and page numbers of lines that:

1. Begin with -
2. Followed by whitespace
3. Then a chapter title
4. Then the page #, like so: #page=9&

Here's an example of the raw text I'm working with:

```
|   "Principles of Microeconomics 2e"   (null)
-   "Preface"   #page=9&zoom=0,0,58
|       "1. About OpenStax" #page=9&zoom=0,0,150
|       "2. About OpenStax resources"   #page=9&zoom=0,0,248
|       "3. About Principles of Microeconomics 2e"  #page=9&zoom=0,0,544
|       "4. Additional resources"   #page=13&zoom=0,0,367
|       "5. About the authors"  #page=14&zoom=0,0,58
-   "Chapter 1. Welcome to Economics!"  #page=17&zoom=0,0,58
|       "1.1. What Is Economics, and Why Is It Important?*" #page=18&zoom=0,0,338
|       "1.2. Microeconomics and Macroeconomics*"   #page=22&zoom=0,0,448
|       "1.3. How Economists Use Theories and Models to Understand Economic Issues*"    #page=23&zoom=0,0,565
```

My current regex:
`(?:\-\s)(["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?(?:page=)(?<=\=)(.*?)(?=\&)`

Currently using this regex matches the entire line, but doesn't put the desired elements into seperates groups.. And I'm having trouble doing this seperation.

current output:
[current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAogu.png)

desired output:

```
Match 1: "Preface" #page=9&
Group 1: Preface
Group 2: 9

Match 2: "Chapter 1. Welcome to Economics!"  #page=17&
Group 1: Chapter 1. Welcome to Economics!
Group 2: 17
```

I am trying to extract the title in one group, and the page number in another.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with

```sh
sed -En 's/^-.*"([^"]+)".*page=([[:digit:]]+).*/\1\n\2/p' file
```

```
Preface
9
Chapter 1. Welcome to Economics!
17
```

sed does not use PCRE, so you don't have non-capturing parentheses or lookarounds, etc

---

Update to address the new desired output.

sed, not having arbitrary variables, will have a hard time counting the matches. Using GNU awk with the same regex:

```sh
gawk '
    match($0, /^-.*"([^"]+)".*page=([[:digit:]]+)/, m) {
        printf "Match %d: %s\n", ++n, m[0]
        printf "Group 1: %s\n", m[1]
        printf "Group 2: %s\n\n", m[2]
    }
' file
```

```
Match 1: -   "Preface"   #page=9
Group 1: Preface
Group 2: 9

Match 2: -   "Chapter 1. Welcome to Economics!"  #page=17
Group 1: Chapter 1. Welcome to Economics!
Group 2: 17
```

GNU awk is required for the 3-argument `match()` function.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FPAT="\".*\"|#page=[0-9]+&" }
     /^- /{
       print "Match", ++m ":", $1, $2;

       gsub(/"/, "", $1);               # remove all "
       print "Group 1:", $1;

       gsub(/[^0-9]+/, "", $2);         # remove all but numbers
       print "Group 2:", $2;

       print ""
     }' file
```

Output:

```
Match 1: "Preface" #page=9&
Group 1: Preface
Group 2: 9

Match 2: "Chapter 1. Welcome to Economics!" #page=17&
Group 1: Chapter 1. Welcome to Economics!
Group 2: 17
```

> `FPAT`:        A  regular  expression  describing  the contents of the fields in a record.

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` program. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk -v RS='-[[:space:]]+"[^"]*"[[:space:]]+#page=[0-9]+' '
RT{
  match(RT,/"[^"]*"/,completeValue)
  printf("Match 1: -   %s\nGroup 1: %s\n",RT,completeValue[0])
  match(RT,/#page=[0-9]+/,pageVal)
  split(pageVal[0],actualpageVal,"=")
  print "Group 2: "actualpageVal[2]
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, setting RS(record separator) as `-[[:space:]]+"[^"]*"[[:space:]]+#page=[0-9]+` regex. Then in main program; matching everything between 1st 2 occurrences of `"` and creating array `completeValue`(which contains complete values in it as per shown samples). Then using `printf` function of `awk` printing 1st 2 required output lines(complete values and Group 1: ones), then again grabbing only digits values out of page values as per requirement and printing it with array actualpageVal.